# ClassLoader не хочет считывать класс

Tags: java

Создал объект `ClassLoader` вот так

```
ClassLoader classLoader = new ClassLoader() {
    @Override
    public Class<?> loadClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        return super.loadClass(name);
    }
};
```

Пытаюсь считать вот так

```
String path = "тут мой полный путь к файлу с расширением .class";
Сlass clazz = classLoader.loadClass(path);
```

Выкидывает ошибку `ClassNotFoundException`

Comment: `name` - это не путь к файлу, это имя класса

Comment: А где он его искать должен?

Comment: в classpath. ClassLoader созданный jvm знает где находиться classpath

Comment: Я написал имя, ничего не изменилось

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример динамической загрузки класса:

```
// Create a File object on the root of the directory containing the class 

file
File file = new File("c:\\myclasses\\");

try {
    // Convert File to a URL
    URL url = file.toURL();          // file:/c:/myclasses/
    URL[] urls = new URL[]{url};

    // Create a new class loader with the directory
    ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(urls);

    // Load in the class; MyClass.class should be located in
    // the directory file:/c:/myclasses/com/mycompany
    Class cls = cl.loadClass("com.mycompany.MyClass");
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
}
```

Как сказали в комментариях, адреса файлов нужно писать в ClassLoader. А точнее даже адрес самой папки. Подробней можно посмотреть [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6219829/method-to-dynamically-load-java-class-files)